# Getting error setting variable in array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, variables

The compiler is coming up with error "symbol not recognized" and am not sure how I am expected to store data in an array. The language is Java and this is just my first program in java so I am testing some things out.

```java
class averageFunction{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int numInput = 0;
        int nummberIn[];
        Boolean loopControl = false;

        while(loopControl = true){
            System.out.print("Please Enter Number, " + numInput + "have been entered...");
            nummberIn(1) = 1;
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: correction, this is _almost looks_ like java

Comment: You have a Book about Java by your side, right?

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of errors:

```
class averageFunction{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int numInput = 0;
        int nummberIn[];//it is null, compiler won't allow to use it
        Boolean loopControl = false;

        while(loopControl = true){//not an error, but it possibly has to be (loopControl == true)
            System.out.print("Please Enter Number, " + numInput + "have been entered...");
            nummberIn(1) = 1;//<-- wrong, nummberIn[1] = 1;
        };//<-- un-expected semi-colon
    };//<-- un-expected semi-colon
};//<-- un-expected semi-colon
```

Comment: Upvote but I think even the compiler would have told him all this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change assignment expression as

nummberIn[i] = 1;

why you are using array because in Your array only 1 element will be there in all cases.??

and also @arvind is showing compile time errors..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array in your program then you first need to define it.

In your program you have written `int nummberIn[];`.

It is just the declaration of an array. You also need to do the following,

`int nummberIn[] = new int[10];`

Here `10` is the size of the array that you can have 10 integer values in this array.

Then you need to access the array by its index.

And **note** that the index of an array **always starts from 0**. For an array of size 10 the indexes will be `0 to 9`.

And to access any individual element you need to do something like the following,

`numberIn[INDEX]`

e.g.

`numberIn[1]`